# Android SQLite and Foreign Key no References error

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I'm implementing a SQLite database in my Android app, here is an exemple:

```
private static final String TABLE_FREQUENCE_ACTIVITE = "frequence_activite";
private static final String FREQUENCE_ACTIVITE_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_FREQUENCE_ACTIVITE + " ("
        + KEY_ID + " Integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, "
        + KEY_LIBELLE + " Varchar (25) NOT NULL);";


private static final String TABLE_UTILISATEURS = "utilisateurs";
private static final String KEY_PSEUDO = "pseudo";
private static final String KEY_INDICE_CALORIQUE = "indice_calorique";
private static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
private static final String KEY_GENRE = "genre";
private static final String KEY_TAILLE = "taille";
private static final String KEY_TAUX_MASSE_GRASSE = "taux_masse_grasse";
private static final String KEY_ID_FREQUENCE_ACTIVITE = "id_frequence_activite";
private static final String UTILISATEURS_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_UTILISATEURS + " ("
        + KEY_ID + " Integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement, "
        + KEY_PSEUDO + " Varchar (25) NOT NULL ,"
        + KEY_INDICE_CALORIQUE + " Integer, "
        + KEY_AGE + " Datetime NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_GENRE + " Char (1) NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_TAILLE + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
        + KEY_TAUX_MASSE_GRASSE + " INTEGER,"
        + KEY_ID_FREQUENCE_ACTIVITE + " INTEGER REFERENCES "+TABLE_FREQUENCE_ACTIVITE+"("+KEY_ID+"));";
```

I just found on google how to use Foreign Key in Android, and when I try to add an "Utilisateur" before adding a "Frenquence_activite" Android is not giving  references error, I don't understand why because if I add "Utilisateur" before adding one row in "frenquence_activite" I have to get an error.

```
    db.addUtilisateur(new Utilisateurs("benjyspider",4000,sdf.format(date),"M",177,12,1));
```

How I add an user:

```
void addUtilisateur(Utilisateurs utilisateur) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_PSEUDO, utilisateur.getPseudo());
    values.put(KEY_INDICE_CALORIQUE, utilisateur.getIndice_calorique());
    values.put(KEY_AGE, utilisateur.getAge());
    values.put(KEY_GENRE, utilisateur.getGenre());
    values.put(KEY_TAILLE, utilisateur.getTaille());
    values.put(KEY_TAUX_MASSE_GRASSE, utilisateur.getTaux_masse_grasse());
    values.put(KEY_ID_FREQUENCE_ACTIVITE, utilisateur.getId_frequence_activite());
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_UTILISATEURS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

Comment: show the create statement and column details of another table.

Comment: @AshishTiwari I edited, thats the add method that you want ?

Comment: Yes, and show the error you are getting in log cat

Comment: @AshishTiwari I don't get error thats the problem I don't have the references error, Iike mysql "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite Foreign Keys are disabled by default. Whenever you open a new connection to the database you need to run the following before executing other statements:

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
```

Otherwise it doesn't take your foreign key constraints into account

Comment: LOOKS GOOD ! Now I can use Select and doing joins ?

Comment: @BJM yes and remember to execute the above statement after you open the database (each time)

Comment: I put it in an @Overrideof onOpen{}

Answer (score 0):

you can try `"FOREIGN KEY (" + KEY_ID_FREQUENCE_ACTIVITE + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_FREQUENCE_ACTIVITE + "(" + KEY_ID + "));";`

I think you should try to give better name (instead of KEY_ID) if you have a lot of table.

Hope it will help

Comment: I already try this, do yu think that references exists in Android Sqlite ?

Comment: I think so, I'm using it in one app. Can you explain what is your problem with references ?

Comment: I don't have the references error, Iike mysql "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails " I can add an rows in "Utilisateur" with an empty "frequence_activite" table

Comment: Okay I see what you mean and do you set this attribute with not null constraint ? Because according to this link if you set null value it works 
https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: Ok I tryed with NOT NULL, but if I put an value, it still accept, and the "frequence_activite_ table still empty

Comment: I'm not sure of that but when you change your "script" to create all tables you have to uninstall your app from your device before rebuild the project. I thought I had this issue

Answer (score 0):

it means table is not referenced correctly. 
Have you used `SQLite` browser to view table contents? If no try this http://sqlitebrowser.org/

You can learn more about Foreign Key here
http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html